# Restructured code leads to ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

I'm trying to restructure my code, but can't seem to figure out what has changed and is causing this exception.

Previously, this was working.

```
private Path getPath() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    ...
    String[] actionFirstSplit = line.split(" ");
    if (actionFirstSplit[1].equals("LOAD")) {
        String[] actionSecondSplit = actionFirstSplit[2].split(",");
    ...
    }
```

It started getting pretty complicated and taking form, so I decided to make a class.

```
public class Interpreter {
    int stepLine;
    String stepName;
    String[] actionFirstSplit;
    String[] actionSecondSplit;

    public String[] parseLine(String line) {
        actionFirstSplit = line.split(" ");
        actionSecondSplit = actionFirstSplit[2].split(",");
        for (String s : actionFirstSplit) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        for (String s : actionSecondSplit) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        return actionSecondSplit;
    }
}
```

I am then calling it like this:

```
private Path getPath() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    ...
    Interpreter action = new Interpreter();
    parametersList = action.parseLine(line);
    ...
    }
```

In the second scenario, I get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    //This line is actionSecondSplit = actionFirstSplit[2].split(",");
    at test.Interpreter.parseLine(Interpreter.java:28)
    at test.Test.getFileOrDirectoryPath(CSU_VM.java:192)
    at test.Test.analyzePath(Test.java:51)
    at test.Test.<init>(Test.java:47)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:264)
```

The print statements are producing the parse results.

The text input may look like this:

```
0 LOAD 1,3
1 LOAD 0,2
2 ADD 1,2
3 SUB 0,1
4 DIV 3,1
5 MUL 0,1
```

Comment: This is not related to being encapsulated or not. This has to do with the fact that the input you  provide now doesn't have 3 elements. You are asking the third element (hardcoded) of an array that has maximum 2 elements

Comment: debug your input. Is there any reason why you left out the check for `arr[1].equals("LOAD");`? It seems that the input doesn´t contain two commatas

Comment: Start printing the length of `actionFirstSplit` before you are performing the `split()`. It will be easier for you to debug. Without the actual content it is very hard to tell of what is going wrong here.

Comment: This is a perfect situation for using your debugger to step through the code to not only help you find the bug, but show you why the program isn't doing what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your codes..

```
actionFirstSplit = line.split(" ");
actionSecondSplit = actionFirstSplit[2].split(",");
```

*Note that `actionFirstSplit[2].split(",");` is trying to work on the 3rd element of the array.*

---

After you split `line`, it stores an array in `actionFirstSplit`. However if the number of elements in `actionFirstSplit` is less than 3.

`actionFirstSplit[2].split(",");` will give you an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` because there is no 3rd element.

---

It is unsafe to hard code it and always presume there will be a 3rd element in `actionFirstSplit`. If you do not want to change your current code, this is what you can do:

**1)** Use a condition to check whether the 3rd element exist:

```
actionFirstSplit = line.split(" ");
if(actionFirstSplit.length >= 3){
    actionSecondSplit = actionFirstSplit[2].split(",");
    //do whatever..
}
```

**2)** Enclose your codes with a try-catch block.

```
actionFirstSplit = line.split(" ");
try{
    actionSecondSplit = actionFirstSplit[2].split(",");
}catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException){
    //perform actions to handle out of bounds
}
```

---

**Add on:**

Your previous code was working because it did a check before splitting further:

```
if (actionFirstSplit[1].equals("LOAD"))
```

It check that it is "LOAD", then there will always be 2 more elements after it.

But in your added codes, there is no check before splitting.

Comment: But in his working code also he was doing the same thing i.e. `String[] actionSecondSplit = actionFirstSplit[2].split(",");`. I guess this question is about why previous code was working and the one after encapsulation is not. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I would have assumed that as well except that he said that his previous code was working, so assuming the data hasn't changed, it must be because he isn't checking for LOAD as he was in his first example.

Comment: @user2004685 That I because in his previous codes, there is a check that the first word is `LOAD` before a further split. But in his edited codes, there isn't any checking.

Comment: @Neil Yes, you are right. But he is just performing the comparison by doing `actionFirstSplit[1].equals("LOAD")` and even if he is not doing it in the solution which is not working it should not throw an error.

Comment: @user3437460 Sorry, But I still do not understand. Even if it is `ADD` instead of `LOAD` it won't throw `Array Out of Bounds Exception`. I understand the added conditions for checking the length etc. but not the above thing.

Comment: @user2004685 It can only mean that he has no strings who's second word is "LOAD" that has more than 2 words in total.  The difference between working code and broken code in this case is that check, in that case, no?

Comment: @user2004685 I can only answer you based on the bits and pieces of information provided by OP. In actual fact, we won't know what other codes are involved and what data files have been used. It could be that the original codes are flawed too, just that it is slightly better than the new codes. Note that OP says `The text input may look like this`. That may not even be the actual data they are using.

Comment: @user3437460 You are absolutely right. It is very hard to identify the problem without the proper inputs.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, you're calling the 2nd split *only* if the 2nd value of the 1st split is "LOAD", while in your second example, you perform no such test.  If it breaks in the 2nd example and not in the first with the same string, then I assume what you need to do is to add back the check, so:

```
public String[] parseLine(String line) {
    actionFirstSplit = line.split(" ");
    for (String s : actionFirstSplit) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    // Ensure that should this condition fail, class state will be consistent
    actionSecondSplit = null;  

    if (actionFirstSplit.length > 2 && actionFirstSplit[1].equals("LOAD")) {
        actionSecondSplit = actionFirstSplit[2].split(",");
        for (String s : actionSecondSplit) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
    return actionSecondSplit;  // May be unassigned!  Careful!
}
```

Also, as a general rule of thumb, you probably shouldn't assume that the first split will result in three values as well, so I added a quick check for that as well.  In the case of an invalid string, `actionSecondSplit` will be null and null will be returned by the method.  If this is not acceptable, consider throwing an `IllegalArgumentException`.